# .htaccess Redirect every request including existing directory to base index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following project structure:

```
Project(root)
  page1\index.php
  page2\index.php
Project\index.php
```

I need to redirect all request to page1\index.php and page2\index.php to base index.php which i am not being able to.

If i go to route page1\index.php or page1\ it goes to page1\index.php but i want it to redirect to base index.php.

My current .htaccess code:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? Keep it in site root directory.

Comment: Yes, its located on site root directory. .htaccess works if there are no directory but for path with directory i cannot  redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```sh
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# skip rule below if URI is already /index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# rewrite to /index.php if URI has /index.php or request
# is for a non-file
RewriteRule /index\.php [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: It still redirects to page1/index.php but not index.php

Comment: Not sure how you are testing because a target of `/index.php` can NEVER rewrite to any subdirectory's `index.php`.